# Warning: /home/websitename/public_html/wp_includes/formatting.php on line 3361

Tags: wordpress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSGxA.jpg)

I get this error when I add a photo plugin to my site.
I use it as a theme. Colibri Page Builder.

Warning: /home/website/public_html/wp_includes/formatting.php on line 3361

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /home/websitename/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 3368.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xvc7.jpg)